# Prevent necessity of InvokeRequired in event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've been writing an API that facilitates communication with a serial port. I'm doing some refactoring and general cleanup and was wondering if there's a way to avoid the following issue.

The main class in the API has the capability to constantly read from the port and raise an event containing a value when the read bytes match a particular regex. The process of reading and parsing occurs on another thread. The event contains the value as an argument (`string`) and because it's being raised from another thread, a client attempting to *directly* assign the value to, say, the `Text` property of a control causes a cross-thread exception unless the handler has the proper `Invoke` code.

I understand why this happens, and when I put the proper invocation code in my test client's event handler, all is well; my question is whether or not there's anything I can do in the API code itself such that clients don't have to worry about it.

Essentially, I'd like to turn this:

```
void PortAdapter_ValueChanged(Command command, string value)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
      {
        receivedTextBox.Text = value;
      }));
  }
  else
  {
    receivedTextBox.Text = value;
  }
}
```

into simply this:

```
void PortAdapter_ValueChanged(Command command, string value)
{
    receivedTextBox.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: That's funny to get 3 answers at nearly same time, but after a half-hour of nothing =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is a common pattern for that used many places in .Net framework itself. For example `BackgroundWorker` uses this model.

For that you'll take a `SynchronizationContext` as a parameter for your API, in this case I assume it is `PortAdapter`.

When raising an event, you raise the event in given `SynchronizationContext` using `SynchronizationContext.Post` or `SynchronizationContext.Send`. Former is asynchronous and latter is synchronous.

So, when client code creating a instance of your `PortAdapter`, it passes `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` instance as parameter. Which means that `PortAdapter` will raise the event in given synchronization context and that also means that you don't need a `InvokeRequired` or `Invoke` calls.

```
public class PortAdapter
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

    private readonly SynchronizationContext context;
    public PortAdapter(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        this.context = context ?? new SynchronizationContext();//If no context use thread pool
    }

    private void DoSomethingInteresting()
    {
        //Do something

        EventHandler handler = SomethingHappened;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            //Raise the event in client's context so that client doesn't needs Invoke
            context.Post(x => handler(this, EventArgs.Empty), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
PortAdapter adpater = new PortAdapter(SynchronizationContext.Current);
...
```

It is very important to create instance of `PortAdapter` in UI thread, otherwise `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be null and hence events will be still raised in ThreadPool thread.

[More about SynchronizationContext here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: Copying SynchronizationContext.Current is the boilerplate approach.

Comment: This option seems to have minimal impact on the codebase (I really don't want to have my class inherit from `UserControl` just to get this to work). At first I saw having to pass in the context as a trade-off when compared to having to call `Invoke`, but since it is an argument to the constructor, at least it's now mandatory and easier to explain in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TBH, the approach with checking for `InvokeRequired` is fine and flexible.

But if you like, you can have all events in your application UI-safe. For this either all classes have to have invocation control *registered*

```
public class SomeClassWithEvent
{
    private static Control _invoke = null;

    public static void SetInvoke(Control control)
    {
        _invoke = control;
    }

    public event Action SomeEvent;
    public OnSomeEvent()
    {
        // this event will be invoked in UI thread
        if (_invoke != null && _invoke.IsHandleCreated && SomeEvent != null)
            _invoke.BeginInvoke(SomeEvent);
    }
}

// somewhere you have to register
SomeClassWithEvent.SetInvoke(mainWindow);

// and mayhaps unregister
SomeClassWithEvent.SetInvoke(null);
```

or have that invocation control exposed, to example:

```
// application class
public static class App
{
    // will be set by main window and will be used even risers to invoke event
    public static MainWindow {get; set;}
}
```

You will have difficulties if event occur when no handle is created or control registered.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the event in the UI Thread, this way the event handler (if any) will already be in the UI thread.

```
public class PortAdapter
{
    public event EventHandler<string> ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(string e)
    {
        var handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            RunInUiThread(() => handler(this, e));
        }
    }

    private void RunInUiThread(Action action)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not good design because you don't know if an handler will perform UI interaction.

Comment: `PortAdapter : UserControl` ? That's nasty. That's a UI abuse

Comment: Removed `UserControl`

Comment: Now that won't compile as `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` are not known :(